# Community Page Visibility Based on Custom Object Property

Tags: community, customer-community

Is there a way to control community page visibility based on custom object property?

While I understand writing component level logic to evaluate this custom object property – can this be done at a page level?  Basically a page-level controller?

For completeness, I am familiar with page-level perms controlled via profile, but in this case I am interested in page visibility based on a custom object property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Manage audience which is part of community page variation to show different variations for different profile.

In your case what you can try is expose the field as as formula field in user object and use that to control visibility of pages

The other option is to use record types and use that to control visibility.

[image]

[image]

Only these are allowed as part of community page variations as of now.

Direct access based on custom object field values(criteria based) is not available yet.